# How to Implement hash(into:) from hashValue in Swift?

Tags: swift, hashable

I don't quite have an idea on what to do with the deprecation warning from the compiler to not use `hashValue` and instead implement `hash(into:)`.

> 'Hashable.hashValue' is deprecated as a protocol requirement; conform
>   type 'MenuItem' to 'Hashable' by implementing 'hash(into:)' instead

The answer from [Swift: 'Hashable.hashValue' is deprecated as a protocol requirement;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395207/swift-hashable-hashvalue-is-deprecated-as-a-protocol-requirement) has this example:

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    switch self {
    case .mention: hasher.combine(-1)
    case .hashtag: hasher.combine(-2)
    case .url: hasher.combine(-3)
    case .custom(let regex): hasher.combine(regex) // assuming regex is a string, that already conforms to hashable
    }
}
```

And I do have this struct, to customise `PagingItem` of Parchment (https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment).

```
import Foundation

/// The PagingItem for Menus.
struct MenuItem: PagingItem, Hashable, Comparable {
    let index: Int
    let title: String
    let menus: Menus

    var hashValue: Int {
        return index.hashValue &+ title.hashValue
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        // Help here?
    }

    static func ==(lhs: MenuItem, rhs: MenuItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.index == rhs.index && lhs.title == rhs.title
    }

    static func <(lhs: MenuItem, rhs: MenuItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.index < rhs.index
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: [How can I update this Hashable.hashValue to conform to new requirements.?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55516776/1187415).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can simply use `hasher.combine` and call it with the values you want to use for hashing:

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(index)
    hasher.combine(title)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two modern options for `hashValue` creation.

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
  hasher.combine(foo)
  hasher.combine(bar)
}

// or

// which is more robust as you refer to real properties of your type
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
  foo.hash(into: &hasher)
  bar.hash(into: &hasher)
}
```

Comment: Just to note: The combine(_:) method is just a convenience operation that takes in a Hashable value, such as an integer or string. Behind the scenes, this combine(_:) method calls the hash(into:) method to mix its value into the Hasher state.